# Chef recipe NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am encountering an issue in my Chef recipe, it suddenly stop working and giving me the error that `**undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass**`

This error is occurring in the following section of my Chef recipe:

```
deploy_user_data_bag = data_bag_item('linux_users', node['machinename'])
deploy_username = deploy_user_data_bag['deploy_user']['username'] if deploy_user_data_bag && deploy_user_data_bag['deploy_user']

mysql_data_bag = data_bag_item('mysql', node['machinename'])
mysql_users = mysql_data_bag['users'] if mysql_data_bag && mysql_data_bag['users']

postgres_data_bag = data_bag_item('postgres', node['machinename'])
postgres_users = postgres_data_bag['users'] if postgres_data_bag && postgres_data_bag['users']
postgres_databases = postgres_data_bag['databases'] if postgres_data_bag && postgres_data_bag['databases']
```

I suspect the issue is related to the data bag items or keys not being present as expected. I have tried to handle nil values with conditional checks, but the error persists.

```
**Additional Information:**
------------
chef_version=14.14.29
platform=centos
platform_version=7.9.2009
ruby=ruby 2.5.7p206 (2019-10-01 revision 67816) [x86_64-linux]
program_name=/bin/chef-client
executable=/opt/chef/bin/chef-client`
```

Any insights into what might be causing this error or suggestions for improvement in my code would be greatly appreciated. Additionally, if there's a better approach to handling data bags in Chef recipes, I'm open to suggestions.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: *I have tried to handle nil values* - can you update the question with an example of how you did this?

Comment: As the log probably said: Give the stacktrace and recipe code. There's a line number somewhere pointing at what is calling [] on a nil object and you need to start from there.